# Merge multiple Boolean data frames into one data frame based on Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three Boolean data frames which are part of the same dictionary. I would like to have as an output one data frame, containing all the true rows.
So if one row is `True` in one of the data frames it's `True` in the output dataframe.
if it's `False` in `All` data frames, it's `False` in the output dataframe.

```
data1 ={"":[True,False,True,False,False]}
data2= {"":[False,True,False,False,False]}
data3= {"":[False,False,False,False,True]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

Expected output:

```
Output_Data= {"":[True,True,True,False,True]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `concat` all dataframes on columns and use `any(axis=1)`

```py
out = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).any(axis=1)
```

```
print(out)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print({'': out.tolist()})

{'': [True, True, True, False, True]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or` on multiple `DataFrame` then convert to the desired dictionary with [`pandas.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) like below.

```
>>> (df1 | df2 | df3).to_dict('list')
{'': [True, True, True, False, True]}
```